# how to show modal popup over the ActiveX object?

Tags: asp.net, activex, activexobject

I have a `modal popup extender` and an `ActiveX object control` in my page, but the popup is showed under the object when I show it.
How to show the popup over the object control?
this is my code:

```
<object id="lablab" clsid="clsid:...." width="100px" height="120px">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

:Wrap it around DIV  TAG then you can easily trap move over event over div & trigger any code you want to

```
<div style="width:100px; height:120px;">
   <object id="lablab" clsid="clsid:...." width="100px" height="120px">
   </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use popup in a div but i can't show this over the popup because object stronger than popup :) , and popup show under the the object .
i use iframe tag !!
and set z-index property that popup over the iframe , iframe stronger than object

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PnlRefer" Width="300px" Style="background-color: #D6D6D6; padding-bottom: 5px; min-height: 145px; display: block; position: absolute; top: -100px;">//my popup
<iframe src="" width="297px"  style="position: fixed;z-index:-1; height:303px;" 
            scrolling="no"></iframe>
<div style="z-index: 1;height: 300px;Width:300px;">
...//content of popup
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```